# Best way to securely send passwords from an application to a user operated server

Tags: tls, passwords

I have the following situation:

- A user sets up a server that will have to receive login details.
- Other users then create accounts and login to this server.

All  this happens only over LAN. I'm thinking of using HTTPS; however as the users will have to setup their own servers, they will not have signed certificates.

How do I make sure that the application is talking to the actual server without requiring (payed) certificates?

Or is there a better way to securely transfer these passwords?

Comment: Are you trying to send credentials to user who created accounts? Or are you trying to transfer credentials to another server?

Comment: @ShaneAndrie The first option, accounts are created by the client

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Internet Protocol Security ([IPSec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec)). This way your LAN communications are both authenticated and encrypted for each IP packet of a communication session. It is not a problem whether your machines are running [Windows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531150.aspx) or [Linux](http://www.elastichosts.com/support/tutorials/linux-l2tpipsec-vpn-server/) based operating systems. Note that you can also use it in conjunction with Layer 2 Tunneling Protocol ([L2TP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_2_Tunneling_Protocol)) that interoperates perfectly with IPSec.

Comment: does it mean that every time a user sets up a server, they have to setup NAT?

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it. Can this all be auto configured without user interference?

Answer (score 2):

I will try to address this at network/protocol level an leave the method you send them (IE email's) up to you. If you have thought on the transfer medium that we can address that as well.

Base on your post, I am guessing these are internal use only and no external access is required. If this is not the case, buy a third part cert.

Internal only, your trying to keep costs down by not buying a third party cert (Just an FYI, this is probably one of the most cost effective ways to both manage a cert, provide security, and provide [Non-repudiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-repudiation))

With self signed certificates, you need to address all three. Starting with the easiest:

**Security (IE Encryption):**

The certificate itself will provide the level encryption you desire. The current minimum security standard at this point I believe is 2048-bit RSA, SHA2 signed certs.

**Managing the certs:**

Now that you have the self-signed cert, how will you manage it? Standard practice is 1-3 years on valid certifications, you can obvious make your cert go longer, but it's frowned on. It easier to manage one cert but even at 3 servers it start to become a problem. There is not silver bullet here, you can manually track it, you can purchase software, you can add a CA server, but it all requires effort.

**Lastly Non-Repudiation:**

This is the most important part, and sadly with self signed certificates, it's also the hardest. Third Party Certificates achieve this through being a Trust CA, used by everyone. You having a Verisign or whomever's certificate means that a level of pre-verification has happen for you company. This also prevent the well know MITM attacks. Self signed certificates don't provide this.

You could load the signing CA (typically the server in self signed certs) into each computer that will be using the site, including the cert used to encrypt with. This can technically prevent MITM attacks, but it's obvious how complex this will get.

You could have a CA server (and use it for managing certs) and you would just need the clients to have the CA server trusted signers cert, but that still has complexity.

Leaving this out make you susceptible to MITM attacks.

@begueradj also provided another solution. [L2TP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layer_2_Tunneling_Protocol) and [IPSec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec). L2TP is not secure by default, which is why IPSec is used (you commonly sees this in VPN's), but this also provides the exact same problems. IPSec requires Key distribution. How will you manage the keys? How will securely sent keys? How will you provide Non-Repudiation?

**TL:DR**
There are solutions and after you go through them all, mostly likely you come to the conclusion that the $500 for a third party certificate (Hell even if it's a wildcard) is what you really want. This only really changes when your organization is large enough where the cost impact changes and teams have the knowledge and expertise to manage CA Server, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would use HTTPS with certificates signed by a CA you create, if you don't want the cost/hassle of using a trusted CA.

Then merely verify your keys against your own CA.  For example see [this guide](http://datacenteroverlords.com/2012/03/01/creating-your-own-ssl-certificate-authority/) for how to create your own CA, and sign your own certificates with this CA, though for your purpose, you do not need to install your root certificate into workstations/browsers (which would get the entire computer to fully trust anything signed by your certificates).

Most HTTPS libraries will allow you to specify the location of the certificate fo your CA for your application to check against.  E.g., in python with requests you define [environmental variable `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/) or in java you add the CA's certificate to [your truststore](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/6nf1il6er/index.html).